# power shell error: Cannot bind parameter

Tags: windows, powershell, shell-scripting

**when i am trying to execute the below PowerShell command, i got error .**

**The command :**

*PS cert:\currentuser\authroot> gci | where subject -like "*UTN*"*

**The error is below :**

Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "subject" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:1 char:12
+ gci | where <<<<  subject -like "*UTN*"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand

I am using windows PowerShell ISE.
a workable solution is highly appreciated

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you are using PowerShell Vs.2, that version had no support for the new `where syntax`.

In version 1 and 2 of PowerShell use:

```
gci | where {$_.subject -like "UTN"}
```

You need to put curly brackets around the expression and refer to any properties with the `$_.` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Hahndorf has already answered this, but I wanted to expand on the error message you received:

> Cannot convert the "subject" value of type "System.String" to type System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"

This is saying that it can't convert a `string` into a `scriptBlock`, which implies that `where` needs to be followed by a script block like so: `{code here}`

Be sure to read the error messages and try to interpret what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

Use "-match" to find UTN that could be anywhere in the subject

```
gci | ?{$_.subject -match "UTN"}
```

If you use "-like" and nothing shows up, put what you're looking for between asterisks inside of quotes.

```
gci | ?{$_.subject -like "*UTN*"}
```